# que significa el []. de este codigo

Tags: javascript

Hice este código con ayuda de un video de youtube pero no explica porque hizo el `[]`.

No se si esta guardando o que.

```js
function quickSort(array) {
  
  if(array.length < 1){
    return [];
  }
  else{

    let left = [];
    let rigt = [];
    let pivot = array[0]
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
      if(array[i] > pivot){
        rigt.push(array[i])
      }
      else{left.push(array[i])}
    }
    ---->return [].concat(quickSort(left), pivot,quickSort(rigt))<----
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eso se hace para que se puedan juntar los arreglos, ya que si no se pone el [] no se puede usar la funcion

```js
concat(quickSort(left), pivot,quickSort(rigt))
```

debido a que este, no sabe a que concatenarlo

Answer (score 0):

Los `[]` se utilizan para inicializar un arreglo donde se van a almacenar elementos. En el caso de aplicar Quicksort, se necesitan arreglos cuyo elementos van a ser ordenados, estos arreglos tienen que ser inicializados con los `[]` en una variable.

```
let left = []; //inicializamos a la variable left como un arreglo vacío
let rigt = []; //inicializamos a la variable right como un arreglo vacío
```

Te recomiendo ver esta [guía](http://www.etnassoft.com/2017/03/24/algoritmos-de-ordenacion-en-javascript-revision-es6/) de los conceptos básicos sobre Quicksort y el uso correcto de Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Te comento el código linea por linea

```javascript
function quickSort(array) {
  
  //verificamos la longitud del array recibido
  if(array.length < 1){
    //si la longitud del array es 0   returnamos un array vacio (por eso el [])
    return [];
  }
  else{
    //definimos la variable left con un valor inicial de array vacio
    let left = []; 
        //definimos la variable right con un valor inicial de array vacio
    let right = [];
        //definimos la variable pivot con un valor inicial del primer elemento de la variable array recibida
    let pivot = array[0]
    //recorremos la variable array
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    
      if(array[i] > pivot){
        right.push(array[i])
      }
      else{left.push(array[i])}
    }
    
    //mesclamos los array  left  y right
    ---->return [].concat(quickSort(left), pivot,quickSort(right))<----
  }
}
```